# A basic question on limit of a sequence of events

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Suppose we have an increasing sequence of events $(A_n)$, then is the following a definition or does it need a proof?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$

If it is a definition how to prove that it is well-defined and if it needs a proof what is the proof?

Comment: $\lim$ isn't really defined for sets; but a common "abuse" of notation is to write $\limsup$ in this context.

Comment: @T.Bongers One can define the notion of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ for sets, there is no abuse whatsoever.

Comment: is it through indicator function ? because that is the only way to represent a set by some number

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes, "abuse" was perhaps too strong a word; but it does bear mentioning that it's rather different from $\limsup$ in terms of sequences, as there isn't the same notion of "convergence."

Comment: ... but $\limsup$ is rather defined as $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A_m$. (Opps, I see - here we have an increasing sequence to begin with)

Comment: +1 because it's tripping up people who are much more knowledgeable than me.

Answer (score 4):

One usually defines $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{k\geqslant n}A_k$$

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}A_k$$

and defines $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ to equal any of them when they do indeed coincide.

Since your sequence is increasing, meaning $A_1\subseteq A_2\cdots$, you can simply define $$\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1} A_n$$

for in this case $$\bigcap_{k\geqslant n} A_k=A_n$$ $$\bigcup\limits_{k \geqslant 1} {{A_k}}  = \bigcup\limits_{k \geqslant 2} {{A_k}}  =  \cdots $$

so both $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ will coincide and equal the union. There is a nice exposition about convergence of sets in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Sequences_of_sets).

Comment: That first definition would make $\lim A_n = \liminf A_n$

Comment: So nothing - I just wanted to add that it should be mentioned that $\{\,x: \lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_n(x)=1\,\}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Hmm... let me check again.

Comment: Also, so far I have seen $\lim$ of set only if $\lim\sup=\liminf$ (which happens to be the case here). Cf. http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Limit_of_Sets and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit where the condition that the limit exists for all $x$ is added

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I hope all is better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $(A_n)$ is an increasing sequence of events means
$$A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots\subset A_n\subset\cdots$$
so 
$$A_n=\bigcup_{p=1}^n A_p$$
so by definition
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n= \bigcup_{p=1}^\infty A_p$$